# Has signed/unsigned aliasing rule ever worked as intended?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing, reinterpret-cast, type-punning

Here is the rule ([basic.lval]/8) in its C++17 form, but it looks similar in the other standards ("lvalue" instead of "glvalue" in C++98):

> 8 If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> (8.4) — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object

The rule sounds like "You'll have UB, unless you do X", but this does not mean that if you do X, you won't get UB, as one might expect! And indeed, doing X is conditional or unconditional UB, depending on the version of the standard.

Lets look at the following code:

```
int i = -1;
unsigned j = reinterpret_cast<unsigned&>(i);
```

What is the behavior of this code?

#### C++98 and C++11

[expr.reinterpret.cast]/10 (/11 in C++11) (emphasis is mine):

> An lvalue expression of type T1 can be cast to the type “reference to T2” if an expression of type “pointer
>   to T1” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to T2” using a reinterpret_cast. That is, a
>   reference cast reinterpret_cast(x) has the same effect as the conversion
>   *reinterpret_cast(&x) with the built-in & and * operators. ***The result is an lvalue that refers
>   to the same object as the source lvalue*, but with a different type**.

So `reinterpret_cast<unsigned&>(i)` lvalue refers to the `int` object `i`, but with `usigned` type. Initialization needs the value of the initializing expression, which formally means that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to the lvalue.

[conv.lval]/1:

> **An lvalue of** a non-function, non-array **type T can be converted to an rvalue**. If T is an incomplete
>   type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. **If the object to which the lvalue refers is not
>   an object of type T** and is not an object of a type derived from T, or if the object is uninitialized, **a program
>   that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior**.

Our lvalue of `unsigned` type does not refer to an object of `unsigned` type which means that the behavior is undefined.

#### C++14 and C++17

In these standards the situation is a bit more complicated, but the rules have been slightly relaxed. [expr.reinterpret.cast]/11 tells the same:

> The result refers to the same object as the source glvalue, but with the specified type.

The offending wording about UB has been deleted from [conv.lval]/1:

> **A glvalue of** a non-function, non-array **type T can be converted to a prvalue**. If T is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. **If T is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of T**. Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is T.

But which value the L-to-R conversion reads? [conv.lval]/(2.6) (/(3.4) in C++17) answers this question:

> … the value contained in the object indicated by the glvalue is the prvalue result

`unsigned` lvalue `reinterpret_cast<unsigned&>(i)` indicates the `i` `int` object with the value `-1` and the prvalue resulting from L-to-R conversion has `unsigned` type. [expr]/4 says:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

`-1` is definitely is not in the range of representable values for the `unsigned` type of the prvalue expression, so the behavior is undefined.

The behavior would be defined if the `i` object contained a value from the [0, INT_MAX] range.

The same reasoning is applicable in the case when an `unsigned` object is accessed through an `int` glvalue. This is UB in C++98 and C++11 and UB in C++14 and C++17 unless the value of the object in the [0, INT_MAX] range.

So, in contrast to a popular belief that this aliasing rule allows to reinterpret an object as containing a value of corresponding signed/unsigned type, it does not allow it. For the values in [0, INT_MAX] range, objects of signed and unsigned types have the same representation ("*The range of non-negative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type, the representation of the same value in each of the two types is the same*" says [basic.fundamental]/3 in C++17). It is hard to call such an access a "reinterpretation", not to mention this was unconditional UB prior to C++14.

What is the purpose of the rule ([basic.lval]/(8.4)) then?

Comment: Well it looks like the rule allows one to use either signed or unsigned version of a type to access values in the range common to both versions. It seems the purpose of the rule is to allow just that, since no oher rule does. It doesn't give one broader permissions because why would it? It isn't quite clear what else you expect from the standard to say and/or allow.

Comment: @n.m. Prior to C++14, even accessing the values in the overlapping range was not allowed.

Comment: It was a problem in the standard back then, fixed now. C hss this provision since at least C99.

Comment: @n.m. if you believe that the only intent was to allow accessing objects with the values within the overlapping range (and C99 rationale agrees here), why not turn this comment into an answer?

Comment: Maybe later, don't have much time to write a proper answer right now.

Comment: Your interpretation appears to constrain access through narrow character lvalues, which a considerable number of rules in the Standard go to great length to explicitly allow aliasing through.  From this, I conclude that your interpretation of the rules does not match the intended meaning or usual reading.

Comment: In situations where one part of the Standard defined the behavior of some actions, but a different part indicated that an overlapping category of actions invoked UB, the authors of the C Standard, and presumably the C++ Standard as well, expected compiler writers to recognize that they should uphold the Spirit of C, including "Don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done" whether or not the Standard actually required them to do so.  Consequently, no version of either Standard has ever made any real effort to resolve all such conflicts.

Comment: @BenVoigt since the Standard almost never defines objects representation, an attempt to access an object through a glvalue of character type will almost always lead to UB.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: It's certainly not UB, but implementation-defined.  See the Standard language around "object representation" and the strict aliasing rule itself

Comment: @BenVoigt https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/impldefindex enumerates 3 cases of implementation-defined behavior related to types representation. Namely, "representation of char", "value representation of floating-point types", "value representation of pointer types". Let's say I haz a struct with only one non-static member of a reference type. Where the Standard defines the result of accessing an object of this type through a char glvalue?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: If by "result", you mean the numeric values seen, nothing defines that.  The *behavior* is defined.  What the object representation contains is unspecified, but that there is an object representation, that its size can be determined via `sizeof`, and that lvalues of type `std::byte` or `unsigned char` can be used to inspect it -- these are guaranteed by `[basic.types]` and `[basic.lval]`

Comment: As of this section from reinterpret_cast: `...AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType...`, i.e., the cast itself(!) is well defined and even each outcome on every machine will be fully deterministic for that individual machine, only dependent on the implementation details of the object representation. So the question is not about UB, but about the (value focused) relation of this reinterpretation to well defined signed unsigned conversions. ( n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. 's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the subject of the [defect report 2214](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2214), which says:

> Section: 6.9.1  [basic.fundamental]     Status: C++17     Submitter: Richard Smith     Date: 2015-12-15
>
> [Adopted at the February/March, 2017 meeting.]
>
> According to 6.9.1 [basic.fundamental] paragraph 3,
>
> > The range of non-negative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value representation of each corresponding signed/unsigned type shall be the same. *(This is the wording in C++11 and C++14 versions, though the paragraph numbers may be different -- n.m.)*
>
> The corresponding wording from C11 is,
>
> > The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of the same value in each type is the same.
>
> The C wording is arguably clearer, but it loses the implication of the C++ wording that the sign bit of a signed type is part of the value representation of the corresponding unsigned type.
>
> Proposed resolution (January, 2017):
>
> Change 6.9.1 [basic.fundamental] paragraph 3 as follows:
>
> > ...The standard and extended unsigned integer types are collectively called unsigned integer types. The range of non-negative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type, **the representation of the same value in each of the two types is the same**, and the value representation of each corresponding signed/unsigned type shall be the same. The standard signed integer types...

So this apparently was the intent all along. C++17 has just fixed the wording.

C and C++ standards never intended to allow reinterpreting negative values as unsigned or vice versa. There are several signed integer representations in the wild (e.g. one's complement, two's complement, sign-and-magnitude) and the standard doesn't mandate any of them, so it cannot prescribe effects of such reinterpretation. They *could* have been made implementation-defined, but considering the possibility of trap representations, there's no real benefit in that. "An implementation-defined result or a trap" is as good as "undefined".

Comment: Could you state more clearly that the intent was to allow accessing non-negative values from signed type range and not reinterpret negative values representation as unsigned values? Adding a reference to ANSI C rationale (https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c3.html#3-3): "The lvalue types may differ in signedness.  In the common range, a signed integral type and its unsigned variant have the same representation; it was felt that an appreciable body of existing code is not ``strictly typed'' in this area."

Comment: Language vandals embrace the notion that accessing an object of a type which would be allowed to have trap representations should not be expected to behave predictably *even on implementations where the type is documented as not having any trap representations*.  There's zero evidence that the authors of the Standard intended quality implementations to behave likewise.  Having an action invoke UB when done on a type with trap representations, but not when done on a type without trap representations, would make not only make sense, but it makes *so much sense* that...

Comment: ...only someone who was being deliberately obtuse would fail to recognize that quality implementations should be expected to behave in such fashion except when intended for specialized purposes like ensuring that code will be compatible with obtuse implementations.

Comment: @supercat Apparently an opportunity for the compiler to assume that some things are impossible and to optimize away a corner case is more important than code reliability, or even the principle of minimum surprise. So much for "high level assembly".

Comment: @supercat UB is not a prescription but an absence of one. Since there is no reasonable for all implementations behaviour to define, the standard leaves it undefined. Nothing prevents an implementation from documenting behaviour in this case. There is no requirement to behave unpredictably. OTOH requiring defined behaviour unless there are trap representations doesn't make any sense, because trap representations are exactly representations that cause UB (not a hardware interrupt or anything). 'Behave predictably unless you behave predictably". Yeah, every implementation is already doing that.

Comment: @n.m.: Loading an Indeterminate Value of anything other than an object of character type whose address is taken invokes UB, *even if the type in question has no trap representations*.  Rather than characterizing things in that fashion, the Standard shouid have provided that implementations may define different storage formats for objects based upon whether their address is taken, and said that e.g. a `uint32_t` whose address is taken cannot have padding bits or trap representations, but one whose address isn't taken might.

Comment: @supercat C++ should evolve in a direction of having more and more UB, not less

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: What useful purpose would that serve?  The supposed "optimization benefits" from UB evaporate if programmers to add extra code to ensure that the program's behavior is fully defined for all possible input bit patterns they may receive.  Outside of the rare scenarios where programs will never receive input from potentially malicious sources, the "modern" approach to UB is in every way inferior to approaches involving *loosely* specified behaviors.

Comment: @supercat _What useful purpose would that serve?_ UB == fun. More UB == more fun.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The C Standard already allows a conforming implementation to behave in any fashion whatsoever when given any particular source text that is free of constraint violations and `#error` directives; its authors even recognize the possibility that one could write a "conforming" implementation that satisfied the One Program Rule by processing a single contrived and useless program, and would jump the rails when given anything else.  How much more fun could one want?

Comment: @supercat I've never heard about this. Any details/references?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf more notably 5.4.2.1 "While a deficient implementation could probably contrive a program that meets this requirement, yet still succeed in being useless, the C89 Committee felt that such ingenuity would probably require more work than making something useful."  The Committee vastly overestimated the amount of work to produce a conforming-but-useless implementation ("If given the One Program, behave as required; otherwise do whatever" would suffice) but I don't think they thought it should matter.